# writing sql query with php prepared query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write mysql query with php prepared query.

First, the query

```
    $query="delete from friends  where UserA=?, UserB=? 
    or (UserB=?, UserA=?)";
```

I want to delete friends entry from database. The entry can be in any order. Like, a friends relation can be entered as `UserA` to be friend of `UserB` or `UserB` to be friend of `UserA`. But there is only one entry anyway. So to check make sure the entry is deleted I am trying to find and delete it in any of both possible cases.

Second,
I am confused with passing the parameters to the above sql query. The parameters in the above query are four. So I am guessing to pass four parameters. But I think if i do it `$stmt->bind_param('ii',$userAid, $userBid)` this should work???

```
$stmt=$mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('iiii',$userAid, $userBid, $userAid, $userBid);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: just edit your query: `$query="delete from friends  where (UserA=? AND UserB=?) OR (UserB=? AND UserA=?)";`. you should use "AND", not ",". the rest seems fine

Comment: @CaptainCrunch  and The number of parameters? two or four?

Comment: four parameters. one for each "?"

Comment: @CaptainCrunch if you think your comment is an answer then when don't you answer instead commenting?

Comment: i wasn't sure what you were asking, so i commented. thnx for you're comment, i've summed it all up to the answer bellow. please let me know if it lacks anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets sum it all up:

```
/* fixed the query */
$query="delete from friends where (UserA=? AND UserB=?) OR (UserB=? AND UserA=?)";

/* invoke the query */
$stmt=$mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($query);
// (1 parameter for each "?" )
$stmt->bind_param('iiii',$userAid, $userBid, $userAid, $userBid);
$stmt->execute();
```